# Mockito Null pointer exception for mocked object. New to mockito as well mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, nullpointerexception, mockito

I have a class ConfigurationEventDatabse which deals with mondo db collections and have db methods. I had to create an Index for one of the field. I put Index as shown in below code

```
@PostCunstruct 
Private void init(){
MongoClient = mongoUtil.init();
collection = mongoUtil.initCollection(mongoClient, databaseName, EventCollections.Configuration_Events);
collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending(EventFields.Sequence_Field));
```

Test class

```
@Mock
private MongoUtil mockedMongoUtil

@Mock
private MongoClient mockedMongoClient

@Mock
private MongoCollection<Document> mockedCollection

@Before
public void setup(){
Mockito.when(mockedMongoUtil.init()).thenReturn(mockedMongoClient);
Method postConstruct = ConfigurationEventDatabase.class.getDeclaredMethod("init");
postConstruct.setAccessible(true);
postConstruct.invoke(db); //db refers to class under test
}
```

I am getting npe at "collection.createIndex" line. I tried to mock collection.initCollection and others things also, but npe still persist. Don't want to create a separate method for it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: considering you have this: MongoClient = mongoUtil.init(); I'm surprised it even compiles.

Comment: `initCollection` is not mocked

Comment: Tried with mocking but still issue is there. Avoided to write it because it is part of solution.

Comment: @Stultuske and `@PostCunstruct`

Comment: @havryliuk didn't even see that one. At least we understand why the code doesn't work.

Comment: Did we have something on this?